# How to install Broadcom Gigabyte 57xx

Tags: drivers, broadcom

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed the OS in my computer and the system tells me I have no NIC. Apparently the OS can not see my on-board NIC. I downloaded 6 various packages for the Broadcom NIC and every time I paste the install script in a terminal I get error messages RPM is not in the neighborhood.

So I downloaded RPM from 3 sources, can't get that to install either.

I have watched several youtube videos and everything just seems to work when they do their installs. Every time I type what they type (and it works for them) it does not work.

Are there any clearer instructions for someone who is a newbie. I have spent 4 days just getting the system installed, 2 days trying to get a NIC to work. I expected a learning curve, but even the instructions require research...

Thanks and forgive me for asking such basic questions.

Excuse me, I was unaware that editing was the best way, I do want to keep the process easy and efficient. Thanks for the tip.

The "additional drivers list" is blank and I do not see any icon for "Software Updates".

Up-date:
Last evening I turned on the computer and the NIC appeared with all of the TCP_IP information and I could browse. I performed a system up-date, rebooted and when it came up the NIC only had a MAC address.

Back to square one...

I found another possible solution however it requires that I compile the driver into the kernel. there are lines to place in the kernel configuration file. Is there another program you and download that allows you to edit the Kernel Configuration file?

All of the links and tips I find on these boards make reference to wireless drivers, I do not think that will work on this Broadcom BCM5751 Integrated Ethernet NIC.

The last instructions will not help me. My Broadcom is integrated as in soldered down to the mother board. The computer that I have is a Dell SX280, there are no expansion slots for any cards. The ubuntu OS is only showing a MAC address for the BCM5751

Thanks for the reply

Update:

The NIC finally began working sort of..., after approx 45 minutes it stops working, the TCP/IP info disappears and I have to re-boot to get it back.

I do not know how to begin troubleshoot this network driver..., If I drop the XP harddrive in the computer and boot on XP, all is fine, the nic never quits.

ALSO, when go to UPDATE, the nic will dump the TCP/IP info and STOP working immediately.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems your NIC drivers are in RPM format, which are not directly usable in Debian(Ubuntu) distros. Try to install `alien` (with Software Center). This utility can convert and install rpm packages.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that these programs lack any meaningful instruction, I downloaded a file named alien.1p.gz. It looked like it needed to be extracted so I did that. I then doubled clicked on it and nothing happened.

Comment: I was poking around and found this: sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43     After I ran those via terminal, my ethernet chip started working, I have an address, DNS, and subnet. Now all I have top do is get my video and audio working.

Comment: I have not been able to figure out this Alien software, it also fails to install and has no clear directions on how it works. After several hours of trying to get it installed, I figured it too was not compatible with Ubuntu.
My NIC is able to obtain an IP address at bootup burt it only last for 2 or 3 minutes before all that disappears and the system reports that I do not have a NIC installed.
I have watched several Youtube videos and I do not get the results they do when I try their solutions, I get "command not supported" and errors like that.

R there any other solutions that might work?

Comment: If your installation of linux-firmware-nonfree has succeeded, you should have the Broadcom driver in the `additional drivers` list of the `Software Updates` settings. Check if it is there and select it if needed. BTW, you should edit your question instead of writing comments. It will get more attention !